# How to grant MS Graph's User.Read.All privilege to any SharePoint Online user through an Azure App?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, azure-ad-graph-api, adal, msal

In a **SharePoint Online** (SPO) environment, I am trying to let any (non-admin) user query **Microsoft Graph** API information that requires the `User.Read.All` permission.

=> The aim is to make **my own directory** (any user would be able to search for anybody in the organization's Azure Active Directory (AAD)) because Office 365's **Delve** and **Contacts** do not show all the fields from the AAD (especially `extensionAttributes`). Also my site uses a custom masterpage.

*Note: AAD users are not all in the SPO website so I can't use SP's API such as `query`, `SP.user`, `siteusers`.*

It works well when I authenticate through the App using its `client_secret`, but when I authenticate through SharePoint via [ADAL JS](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) or [MSAL JS](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) (silent or popUp auth) I am granted only the `User.Read` (not `.All`) privilege.

I have updated the **Azure App manifest** to specify that the privilege should be granted for users coming from the App:

```
"appRoles": [
        {
            "allowedMemberTypes": [
                "Application",
                "User"
            ],
            "description": "Annuaire",
            "displayName": "Annuaire",
            "id": "d1613ef0-097a-44a0-b1d2-c13c02231a97",
            "isEnabled": false,
            "lang": null,
            "origin": "Application",
            "value": "User.Read.All"
        }
    ],
```

Using [JWT.io](https://jwt.io/) to analyze the tokens, I can see that when I request it from the connection made using the `app_secret` I have the following role:

```
{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/e6f27e96-***/",
(...)
  "roles": [
    "User.Read.All"
  ],
(...)
}
```

But when I request it from the SharePoint page using ADAL or MSAL I have only the following scope:

```
{
  "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/e6f27e96-*****/",
(...)
  "scp": "User.Read",
(...)
}
```

I have also tried to use **AAD Graph** API with `Directory.Read.All` permission but the result is the same.

What shall I do to build my custom directory?

Comment: What permissions have you granted in azure if you look at the graphical interface

Comment: Here are the permissions: https://imgur.com/5eVgzj0

Comment: Have you granted the permissions in the azure portal? Actually pressed the button for granting permissions after you checked the checkbox?

Comment: Yes, on the screenshot the 4th column indicated which permissions require admin consent and the last column indicates that these permissions have been granted by the tenant administrator.

Comment: Additional settings from the App properties: https://imgur.com/a/55g63Pz

Comment: See my answer below, I may have miss understood your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your provided screenshot i can see that the permission for User.Read.All is an application permission and not a Delegated permission that the MSAL and ADAL library uses together with the users credentials.

So set the correct permission User.Read.All as a Delegated permission and i think it will work.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've made a second app with Delegated permissions instead of Application permissions. Now I'm rewriting part of MSAL code because I'm getting this message `ClientAuthError: User login is required.` => Working on it, will keep you posted.

Comment: Great! I can only point you to the following github issue: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/741 Where the latest comment where added a week ago. So there seems to be a bug atm.

Comment: @AshorLivs If i look into the documentation of msal they also user the scope User.ReadWrite when logging in. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-sign-in#sign-in-with-redirect

Comment: Johan, did you know that I've struggled for like 30 hours before posting? Now it looks like you found the culprit! Here's a login + token request + MSG query response: https://imgur.com/a/4FwkdtV

Despite the acquireTokenSilent (which is out of this topic scope) I've finally achieved to use my Azure App as intended thanks to your answer!

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Comment: If it may helps someone else, here's an output of the scopes received in the token (decoded with JWT.io) after implementing Johan's answer:

```json
{
  "aud": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/e6f27e96-*****/",
(...)
  "scp": "Directory.Read.All User.Read profile openid email",
(...)
}
```